# bash expressions

Tags: bash

In a bash script I have the following section.

```
if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
   set -- mongod "$@"
fi
```

What does the expressions `${1:0:1}` and `set -- mongod "$@"` ?

Answer (score 2):

`${parameter:offset:length}` is "Substring  Expansion". (See Parameter Expansion in `man bash`).

`set`, among other things, can set positional parameters:

> The remaining n ARGs are positional
>       parameters and are assigned, in order, to $1, $2, .. $n.

So, the expression prepends `mongod` to the positional arguments.